# xarray create new dataset with same lat/lon grid as another file

Tags: python, geospatial, netcdf, python-xarray

I am working with a Land Surface Model that I want to test with some dummy data. There is one dataset that is read in with no errors. It is the soil data below:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 1, x: 200, y: 200)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) float64 1.051e+04
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Data variables:
    t_clay     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    t_sand     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    t_silt     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    t_sum      (time, y, x) float32 ...
    s_clay     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    s_sand     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    s_silt     (time, y, x) float32 ...
    s_sum      (time, y, x) float32 ...
    latitude   (y, x) float64 40.0 40.0 40.0 40.0 40.0 ... 50.0 50.0 50.0 50.0
    longitude  (y, x) float64 0.0 0.0656 0.1312 0.1968 ... 15.4 15.48 15.56
Attributes:
    Conventions:     CF-1.0
    content:         HARMONIZED WORLD SOIL DATABASE; first it was aggregated ...
    scaling_factor:  20
```

I want to use the SAME `latitude` / `longitude` grid from this `xr.Dataset` in my other variables.

For example the radiation data (randomly generated values) looks as below:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 600, longitude: 600)
Coordinates:
    time       datetime64[ns] 2000-02-14
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 26.024994 26.074997 ... 55.924988 55.97499
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 17.974998 17.924995 ... -11.925003 -11.974998
Data variables:
    Rg         (latitude, longitude) float32 1.09 1.0 0.28 ... 0.51 0.13 0.07
```

#### 1. I need to create a new `xr.Dataset` with the same shape as the soil data above.

#### 2. I also need the `longitude` & `latitude` `Coordinates` to be stored as `Data variables`.

The Fortran is having trouble reading 'longitude' when it is stored as a `Coordinate` rather than a `Variable`

Thanks!

Comment: So.... What did you try yourself...? What didn't work...? I didn't downvote, but see: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: I managed to fix it after grabbing a coffee (had been tearing my hair out all morning about this). It turned out I was alot closer than I had thought. Shall I delete the question or post an answer? Thank you for your information!

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to make samples from the data in the other `xr.Dataset` object by using the following code:

#### 1. Import Packages

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from shutil import copyfile
import os

np.random.seed(123)
```

#### 2. initialise the 'skeleton' from the soil data

```
s = xr.open_dataset(s_dir)

# drop all but ONE variable!
s = s.drop(["t_clay","t_silt","t_sum", "t_sand", "s_clay", "s_sand", "s_silt"])

# can extend this list to include a number of variables
variables = ["Rg"]
```

#### 3. Loop over each variable, randomly drawing values from the variable of interest (`Rg`) and inserting into the skeleton provided by the old `xr.Dataset`.

```
for var in l:
    filename = data_dir + "{}_dummy.nc".format(var)
    print("** Creating file: ", filename, " **")

    # copy file and open the new temp file
    copyfile(filename, data_dir + "temp.nc")
    ds = xr.open_dataset(data_dir + "temp.nc")

    # generate randomly from variable in another xarray object
    s.s_sum.values = np.random.choice(
        ds[var].values.flatten(), size=s.s_sum.values.shape
    )
    ds = s.copy()
    ds = ds.rename({"s_sum": var})

    ds.to_netcdf(filename, format="NETCDF3_CLASSIC")
    print("File Created!")

    # remove temporary file
    os.remove(data_dir + "temp.nc")
    print("Temporary Data Removed")

    del ds
```

I think that this routine could be really useful for other people who need to generate random forcing data for hydrological and climatological models.